# Como parseo xml por php a través de una url

Tags: php, xml

Estoy creando un reproductor con una radio del hosting radionomy y para eso necesito del parseo, alguien me podría ayudar?... tengo varios ejemplos de parseos con xml pero es usando un archivo xml en la misma carpeta, quiero saber como hacerlo de una url externa...

**Este es el codigo XMl y se crea como "xml-file.xml"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<library>
    <book>
        <title>PHP and MySQL</title>
        <author>Miguel Alvarez</author>
        <publisher>WebHole</publisher>
        <price>1.99</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>JAVA 123</title>
        <author>WIlliam Vega</author>
        <publisher>WebHole</publisher>
        <price>2.99</price>
    </book>
</library>
```

**Luego se procede a hacer un archivo .php llamado "index.php"**

```
<?php
//para llamar el Archivo xml
$url = 'xml-file.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
// tomar el titulo
$title=$xml->book[0]->title;
// mostrar el titulo
echo $title;
```

Todo este código me funciona a la perfección a la hora de ejecutar el index.php pero no es lo que necesito, lo que necesito es halar los datos xml desde esta url: http://api.radionomy.com/currentsong.cfm?radiouid=b6670937-bb93-4d9e-aab7-508b3731cc52&apikey=1c0a8ecf-1624-418e-a5de-4b1d5014f311&type=xml

Para halar los datos del artista y la canción, pero colocando esa url en la variable $url  el código no se me muestra al ejecutar la index.php necesito de su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

La función  simplexml_load_file() te permite leer archivos XML en PHP 5+ dándote la facilidad de usar los datos como objetos.

```
$xmlstr = 'http://api.radionomy.com/currentsong.cfm?radiouid=b6670937-bb93-4d9e-aab7-508b3731cc52&apikey=1c0a8ecf-1624-418e-a5de-4b1d5014f311&type=xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlstr);
```

Más info en: http://php.net/manual/es/function.simplexml-load-file.php

Answer (score 0):

Usa la función de "PHP file_get_contents". Ejemplo:
`<?php
$página_xml = file_get_contents('http://api.radionomy.com/currentsong.cfm?radiouid=b6670937-bb93-4d9e-aab7-508b3731cc52&apikey=1c0a8ecf-1624-418e-a5de-4b1d5014f311&type=xml');
echo $página_xml;
?>`

Más info en http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: la funcion de file_get_contents no me funciona en el host.. tube que usar Curl para obtener datos pero para usarlo con xml no me da tampoco